# Has a particular 'DayOfMonth' occurred in between 'Date' and today?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have 2 columns:

1. DayOfMonth (which is simply an integer between 1 and 31)
2. Date

I'm trying to write a CASE statement which returns true if the DayOfMonth has occurred in between 'Date' and today's date.

For example, if DayOfMonth = 18 and Date = '2020-04-14', the CASE statement would return True because the 18th April occurred between today and 14th April.

Thanks

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: You should provide a wide range of sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most databases support a `day()` function to return the date of a month.

```
where (DayOfMonth >= day('2020-04-14') and
       DayOfMonth <= day(current_date)
      ) or
      '2020-04-14' <= datedd(month, -1, current_date)
```

Some databases spell `day()` as `extract(day from <date>)`.  Some have alternative ways of writing `current_date`.

EDIT:

This is more complicated than I was thinking, because the day of month could be 31 -- but a month may not have 31 days.  The following does not handle handle February, but it gives the idea:

```
where -- first the trivial case
      (dayOfMonth <= day(current_date) and
       (@date <= date_trunc('month', current_date) or
        dayOfMonth >= day(@date)
       )
      ) or
      -- then the previous month case
      (date_trunc('month', @date) = date_trunc('month', current_date) - interval '1 month' and
       dayOfMonth >= day(@date) and
       dayOfMonth <= day(last_date(@date))
      ) or
      -- Days at the end of month but not necessarily in the previous month.
      @date < date_trunc('month', current_date) - interval '1 month'
```

Comment: This will only work if all dates are within 1 month. Would there be a way of doing it so that, for example, if DayOfMonth = 1 and Date = 2020-03-30, that it would still work?

Comment: @ChrisMarshall . . .  This is quite complicated.  I might suggest that you set up a calendar table.